# Is there an easy way to find dependencies for a subform in Access?

Tags: ms-access

For a given form in a database, is there a quick/easy way to find all other forms in an Access database use it as a subform?

Note: I am only concerned with main forms that have it defined using the property sheet, it is easy enough to do a code search for any form that dynamically sets it as a subform at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on the form in the database window and select "Object Dependencies"  This should give you the list of forms that host it as a sub-form.

Comment: This depend on the version of Access, I guess.

Comment: It also works only if you have Name Autocorrect turned on, and nobody should do that, since it's buggy and causes both performance problems and corruption of Access objects. It's a feature that is completely unusable in reality.

Answer (score 1):

It is not too difficult to use VBA to check.

```
sfrmname="FormToFind"
For Each frm In CurrentProject.AllForms
   DoCmd.OpenForm frm.Name, acDesign
   For Each ctl In Forms(frm.Name).Controls
      If ctl.ControlType=acSubForm Then
         If ctl.SourceObject = sfrmname Then
            Debug.Print frm.Name
         End If
      End If
   Next
   DoCmd.Close acForm, frm.Name
Next
```

Or there abouts.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good answer and I wrote almost the exact code, but was hesitant about opening each object (lord knows what code is in the onopen of some of them). I hadn't considered opening in design view though. Good answer +1